# How to change indexing in magento 1.9 based on name

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to change search index in magento 1.9 ? Basic index is by product id, How to change it to base on their name or save date ?

Comment: Can you tell me the requirement? why you need to change default indexing

Comment: i need to ordering the product by weight

Comment: is this field included only in backend?

Comment: weight is default field in the backend